# Qt include header file from above directory

Tags: c++, qt, header-files

At first, i don't think this will become a problem, but after a few day working with it, i still can't find a solution

```
source
  |
  |--- Model
  |      |
  |      | - A.h
  |-B.h
```

I can't include the B.h from A.h, compiler complain that

"Cannot open include 'B.' : no such file or directory

And this is my .pro file

```
TEMPLATE = app
QT += qml quick widgets sql
QT += declarative
RESOURCES += qml.qrc
include(deployment.pri)
HEADERS += \
   sources/B.h \
   sources/model/A.h
```

A.h

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
#include "source/B.h"
class A {
};
#endIf
```

B.h

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H
class B {

};
#endif
```

How can i fix this? And thank for dropping by

Comment: Sorry, i had edited the question

Comment: Ya, you right. Sorry, again, i'm on middle of something, i should give it a proper check next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path for include file is relative to the source file which is including it. So here in `A.h` you should have :

```
#include "../B.h"
```

Or add that path to the include directories by adding to `.pro` :

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/source
```

And include the header file like:

```
#include "B.h"
```

Comment: If i use relative path, the include error is gone, however, inside my  B.h file, there are a tons of syntax error like missing ';' before '*'.

Comment: The other errors probably relate to some other issues with your code. It's better to provide the code and ask it in a new question.

Comment: Then can i ask one more thing about "include directories"'s way?
I don't really understand  about $$PWD part, is this a variable, or i just write the full absolute path into it?

Comment: `$$PWD` is a qmake variable which specifies the full path to your project working directory. It refers to the location of `.pro` file. Using it you don't need to specify an absolute path. Using an absolute path is not recommended at all, since it would be changed if you change the directory of the project.

Comment: So, since my B.h inside source folder, i should add 
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD\source 
right? I still getting the error like when using relative path, but that mean both way working fine. 
Thank Nejat

Comment: You are right. The include path should be `$$PWD/source`. I have edited the answer.